# Сортировка ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив такого вида:

```
$array = array(
            23 => array(
                'NAME' => 'FIRST',
                'VALUE' => 1,
                'RATE' => 3
            ),
            25 => array(
                 'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                 'VALUE' => 1,
                 'RATE' => 4.1
            ),
            ...

            342 => array(
                'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                'VALUE' => 1,
                'RATE' => 2.7
            )
        );
```

Т.е. изначальное кол-во элементов не известно. Нужно отсортировать по ключу RATE и построить новый массив с учетом этой сортировки. В данном примере например элементы должны идти в следующем порядке: 
25, 23, 342 (при условии, что их изначально три). Еще было бы здорово, если вы предложите вариант, при котором можно выбирать для сортировки только те элементы, у которых RATE больше нуля. Так же, если вы предложите вариант формирования нового массива, в котором можно будет ограничить вывод количества элементов, то это будет просто замечательно. Например: вывести только 3 элемента, у которых значения RATE самые большие. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD.
Вот получившийся рабочий код:**

```
$new_array = array();
        foreach ($array['ITEMS'] as $k => &$v) {

             if ($v['RATE'] > 0) 
                 $new_array[$v['RATE']] = $v;

        }
        //Сортировка, чтобы самые клевые были вверху.
        arsort($new_array);
        //Обрезаем первые три элемента.
        $array['BEST_ITEMS'] = array_slice($new_array, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такой сортировки нужно построить новый массив и отсортировать его. Дальше выводите как душе угодно.

```
$array = array(
            23 => array(
                'NAME' => 'FIRST',
                'VALUE' => 1,
                'RATE' => 3
            ),
            25 => array(
                 'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                 'VALUE' => 1,
                 'RATE' => 4.1
            ),
            ...

            342 => array(
                'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                'VALUE' => 1,
                'RATE' => 2.7
            )
        );

// новый массив
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    // if ($v['RATE'] > 0) { ... } если значение нужно больше нуля
    $new_array[$v['RATE']] = array($k, $v['NAME'], $v['VALUE']);
}

/*
теперь массив выглядит так

$new_array = array(
            3 => array(
                0 => 23,
                'NAME' => 'FIRST',
                'VALUE' => 1
            ),
            4.1 => array(
                 0 => 25,
                 'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                 'VALUE' => 1
            ),
            ...

            2.7 => array(
                0 => 342,
                'NAME' => 'SECOND',
                'VALUE' => 1
            )
        );
*/

// сортируем новый массив по ключу по возрастанию (по убыванию arsort())
asort($new_array);

// выводим только первые 2 строчки нового массива
$line_stop = 2;
$count_line = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $rate => $v) {
    echo 'RATE=' . $rate . ', ' . $v[0] . ', NAME=' . $v['NAME'] . ', VALUE=' . $v['VALUE'] . '<br>';
    $count_line++;
    if ($line_stop == $count_line) break;
}
```

[Работа с массивами](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного запутались в массивах. Сортировка массива подразумевает под собой изменение порядковых номеров (ключей). Это подходит для перечислимых массовов (списков). Со словарями (ассоциативными массивами) такой фокус не проходит, т.к. При сортировке словарей вы теряете ключи.

В данной ситуации если вам необходимо сохранить ключи, их нужно сперва переместить в значение.

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value)
    $value['id'] = $key;
```

Дальше все очень просто, задача переходит в обычную сортировку с использованием функции usort().

Для получения трех максимумов сортируйте по убыванию и обрезайте первые три элемента функцией array_slice() и по необходимости array_reverse() для изменения порядка сортировки обрезанных элементов.

Comment: Спасибо задача решена с учетом передачи значения по ссылке, как вы и написали, что уменьшило размер кода и ускорило работу цикла. Код, который получился добавляю вниз моего вопроса.